# Saving a hyperlinked image from a remote location to a local folder in excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have an Excel sheet containing a list of image hyper links from a remote file server. Currently when I click on a link it will display the image using the default associated program for it, like ACDsee, Fax Viewer etc...

Now I was hoping for a formula that will prompt me to save it in my local folder instead of openning the file in a file viewer.

Below is the current formula I'm using where (A1) is refering the a cell containing the filename along with the file extension:

```
=HYPERLINK("//remote file server/new designs"&(A1)&".jpg","Image")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not really an Excel issue. All Excel does when you click the link is execute it based on your computer's preferences. I don't think there's a specific formula to do what you want. What you could do instead is create a batch script using Excel. Something like:

`="copy ""//remote file server/new designs"&A1&".jpg"&""" C:\local-folder"`

The double-quotes are there because we have to add quotes around your filename.

You can then copy the copy commands into a batch script, or paste them directly into a Command Prompt window.